# Triangle in a circle

Tags: circles

Prove that angle bisector of any angle of a triangle and perpendicular bisector
of the opposite side if intersect, they will intersect on the circumcircle of the triangle.

Answer (score 1):

Preliminary note:

An inscribed triangle is isosceles iff the perpendicular bisector of its base goes through the center of the circle:

[image]

In our case:

We have an inscribed triangle  $ABC$ and we consider the angle bisector $a$:

[image]

The angles $CAD$ and $DAB$ equal. As a result (inscribed angle theorem) $CD=DB$. So we have an isosceles triangle $CDB$. This is the triangle to whose base we construct the bisecting perpendicular $p$.

Because of the statement mentioned as preliminary note, $p$ will go through the origin and the point $D$ produced by $a$.